# (UK - Tier 2 visa) I am a tier 2 visa holder and was overseas (out of UK) when I was dismissed from my job. I am still overseas, can I return to UK?

Tags: visas, uk, passports, legal, tourist-visas

I am a Tier 2 visa holder employed by a professional services firm in London, UK.

I was dismissed from my job 2 weeks ago whilst out out of the UK (was overseas). I left the UK on 31 Nov 18, was dismissed on 13 Dec 18 and returning to UK on 1 Jan 2019. I need to return to the UK to pack up and send back my personal items in my rented apartment back my home country, and also say goodbye to my flatmate and friends.

My question is, can i reenter the UK with no issues? How should I explain my situation to the Immigration officer - should i tell him I am reentering as a tourist ( based on my nationality I don't need a tourist visa) or should i fully explain the situation that led to my current circumstance that I am/was a tier 2 visa holder which expires in 2021 but am no longer employed as I was dismissed whilst holidaying overseas?

Comment: Isn't a `Tier 2 visa` linked to the employer who gave you the sponsorship certificate ? And I am pretty sure the border officer would try to check your employment status with your sponsor if they come to know about you being fired or they suspect something. And I don't think you employer would say that you are still employed with them.I would advise not to try entering with your Tier 2 visa, but use the tourist route as you don't need a visa for that.

Comment: If you are truthful, they **might not** let you in because your visa is only valid for 60 more days, however whether it is good for travel in and out is dicey.. If you do not tell them you have been fired, the chances are they will not know because when the company notifies the home office it takes some time for the databases to be updated. It is your choice what to do. You can also choose to apply for a general visitor visa and return as a visitor to collect your stuff.

Comment: _After termination Home Office will usually curtail (shorten) the remaining validity of the visa to 60 days. This time only starts running once the worker is notified of the decision to curtail the visa and often it can take several weeks before this letter is sent.

The Home Office can use discretion to allow a longer validity for example if there are children who would be affected or if there are medical or other reasons to do so. In this case, it is important to let the Home Office know and provide evidence_ https://www.redwingimmigration.co.uk/tier-2-visa-curtailed/

Comment: If you choose to return surreptitiously without telling Immigration you have lost your job, make sure you return over the weekend when offices are closed so they will not be able to verify by calling your HR Department. Sorry for your situation. This kind of inhumane treatment of foreign workers is standard in many companies. A humane way to terminate a foreign worker on visa is to wait till they return from vacation so they are present to arrange the logistics of returning to their home country.

Comment: I don't require a 'visitor visa', as my nationality allows me to enter UK without a visa as a Tourist (max 6 months stay). I think I will just explain the situation and tell them why I am returning, and also book a 1 way ticket out of the UK back to my home country to show I am leaving on a certain date.